# Can't get into windows/system32

Tags: windows, kali-linux, 32bit

I've Been trying to reset my windows 7 (32 bit) password using Kali Linux. I have read a few pages on doing this.

My method:

```
cd /media/448AF1848AF172B2
cd /Windows/System32/config
```

(After this I would use chntpw SAM)

However every time I try to use cd /Windows/System32/config I get the "No such file or directory" error.

Comment: `/Windows/System32/config` is an absolute path, the howto probably means `cd Windows/System32/config` when in `/media/448AF1848AF172B2`

Comment: See [Objective Security](http://ophcrack.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

1. Use the command mount and check where is the windows `C` partition mounted.
2. `cd /media/XXXXXX` where `XXXX` is the mount point mentioned.
3. Now `cd Windows/System32/config/`